# Why does amp-script not recognize other amp tags in dom

Tags: amp-html

How come when you nest amp-user-notification inside amp-script, amp-script doesn't recognize amp-user-notifaction children as being part of the DOM? If you replace the notification tag with a simple div it works fine. So when I run the following I get undefined const $btn = document.querySelector('#ccpaAccept'); (ccpaAccept is a child of notification) returns undefined in the console.log. When I take it out of the notification tag and put it in a simple div it works fine. Please advise.

Comment: How come you don't share an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

amp-script is a virtual environment inside of a web worker. It clones the actual DOM to create a copy of one in a different browser thread. Since it is not interacting directly with the DOM, but rather an abstracted clone of the node inside of the DOM, it does not have a way to interact with the AMP extensions being used. They are lost at clone time.